# seemingly ignored assignment to variables in head of for-loop

Tags: c, debugging, greatest-common-divisor

```
void main()
{
    int a, b, r;
    //Finf GCD by Eucledian algorithm
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    for( ; b == 0; (a = b), (b = r)){
        r = a % b;
        printf("GCD is %d", a);
    }
    printf("GCD is %d", a);
}
```

Somehow this doesn't work.
I assign a to b and b to r, but this doesn't seem to change the value of a or b.

Comment: ```b``` is updated when ```r``` is updated, every time the loop iterates. The loop goes no further when ```b == 0``` is false. So, the second b is updated, the following loop iteration no longer executes.

Comment: Furthermore, if you have any value OTHER than 0 in the input, your loop will not execute at all.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Add `\n` inside your `printf` control strings (or call `fflush`). **[use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)**

Answer (score 1):

This `for(;b==0;(a=b),(b=r))` sets up the for-loop like this

- do nothing to init anything
- as long as b equals 0 do the loop body
- between loop body executions first copy value of b to a,
  then copy value of r to b

Note that the loop will never execute if b starts off non-zero.
Otherwise the loop will stop executing as soon as b becomes non-zero, from being updated with value of r.

*(This is somewhat compiling an answer from comments, in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions. Credits to dddJewelsbbb. I offer to delete this if they make an answer and ask me to.)*

Answer (score -1):

Find the corrected working code below, which changes the loop condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
  int a, b, r;
  //Finf GCD by Eucledian algorithm
  scanf ("%d %d", &a, &b);

  for (; r > 0; a = b, b = r)
    {
      r = a % b;
    }
  printf ("GCD is %d", a);
}
```

Test by giving inputs: 16, 12

```
16
12
GCD is 4
```

Code explanation:
The code is the direct implementation of Euclid's algorithm to find GCD. Here the divisor (one of the number) is used to obtain a remainder (after dividing the second number as dividend). Next, the remainder becomes the divisor and the earlier divisor becomes the dividend and this process continues till remainder is zero.

There is plenty of scope in the code to make it more elegant and handle corner cases. I corrected the exact same code as minimum as possible to spot the exact error (which was in the for loop condition).